# Running a JAR with certain JDK classes redirected

Tags: java, jar

I have written a List implementation that internally makes use of java.util.ArrayList and java.util.LinkedList. Now, I have a set of JARs that I want to dynamically load and then invoke from Java, but with my implementation redirected everywhere it uses LinkedList or ArrayList.

Is there a way to do this without having to download the source to the JARs, manually replacing everything and then recompiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the Java installation into a new place, compile your code as `java.util.ArrayList` and `java.util.LinkedList` (i.e. compile your code with the `rt.jar` on the classpath).

Then use `jar -u` to put the new classes into `rt.jar`. Since `rt.jar` isn't signed, you don't have to modify anything else.

This gives you a new `rt.jar` for the copy of your Java installation. Replace the file and start the projects using `java` from the new copy. The code will now pick up your versions.

Depending on which Java version you use, you can also try to set the "boot classpath". Create a JAR with your replacement classses and put them first into this classpath. [Documentation for Oracle's VM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html#bootclass).